# Speed up GetResponse of WebRequest?

Tags: c#, web-services, f#

I have the following code:

```
//Send request and get response
let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri("https://www.google.com/))
req.Proxy <- null
req.Method <- WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
use resp = req.GetResponse()
```

It takes approximately 250 ms to get the request which might not seem as that much. But I will be checking about 200 links so I really want this time to decrease. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: Create the WebRequests (to different endpoints) in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using F# asynchronous workflows and parallelize your requests using `Async.Parallel`. You also need to set the .NET limit of number of parallel connections that it allows in order to actually allow the higher level of parallelism. Something like this:

```
open System
open System.Net

ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit <- 20

let checkUrl url = 
  async {
    let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri(url))
    req.Proxy <- null
    req.Method <- WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
    use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()
    printfn "Downloaded: %s" url
    return resp.ContentLength }

[ for i in 0 .. 100 -> checkUrl (sprintf "http://www.google.com?%d" i) ]
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: ...and of course you should use `use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()` to decrease the number of waiting threads.

Comment: @VasilyKirichenko Oops! No idea how I overlooked that. Thanks for the correction!